# JavaScript extend array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array of objects. During the loop I append different properties to each entry.

My question - how do I make sure every entry has all the properties of each entry?

Let's consider this:

```
var myArray = [{A: 1}, {B: 2}, {C: 3}];
```

Now I want to run some elegant one-liner to convert this array into:

```
[{A: 1, B:2, C: 3}, {A: 1, B:2, C: 3}, {A: 1, B:2, C: 3}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An elegant one-liner is a bit difficult without a library. But if you have some kind of `extend` function, then it could be:

```
myArray.map(function(v) { return extend.apply(null, [{}].concat(myArray)); });
```

The `extend` function would require several objects (passed as separate arguments) to be combined. Such a function is available in jQuery as `jQuery.extend`, and underscore.js also has one.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: They're equal, but good catch nevertheless.

Comment: How are they equal ? http://jsfiddle.net/Ypd9d/ Am i missing something ? extend is a jquery function and is not bound to the window object right ?

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: Oh I'm sorry, I thought you meant `$` instead of `jQuery`. I posted `extend` because each framework has its own function name. (One could also use `_.extend` with underscore.js.)

Comment: ah ok, nvm didn't know he's using `underscore.js`