# JavaScript merging objects by id

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

What's the correct way to merge two arrays in Javascript?

I've got two arrays (for example):

```
var a1 = [{ id : 1, name : "test"}, { id : 2, name : "test2"}]
var a2 = [{ id : 1, count : "1"}, {id : 2, count : "2"}]
```

I want to be able to end up with something like:

```
var a3 = [{ id : 1, name : "test", count : "1"}, 
          { id : 2, name : "test2", count : "2"}]
```

Where the two arrays are being joined based on the 'id' field and extra data is simply being added.

I tried to use `_.union` to do this, but it simply overwrites the values from the second array into the first one

Comment: So what you actually want to do is merge the objects.

Comment: Your syntax is invalid.  Do you have a legit example?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688569/javascript-extend-array

Comment: Closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/37057746/1166087.

Comment: @dippas OP wants to merge objects based on ID, not just merge arrays. And de-duplication in those answers won't work on objects anyway.

Comment: No idea how this was closed as a duplicate of either [How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1584370/283366) or [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14446511/283366). As far as I can tell, this question has nothing in common with those

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var mergedList = _.map(a1, function(item){
    return _.extend(item, _.findWhere(a2, { id: item.id }));
});
```

This assumes that the id of the second object in a1 should be 2 rather than "2"

Comment: This won't work if a2 has more items in the array than a1.

Comment: @CAOakley - yes it will. What makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: @AndreaPuddu `_.unionBy` is in Lodash, not Underscore, but good to know!

Comment: @4castle hehe lodash, of course... anyone still using underscore? :P

Comment: Fantastic answer, Ive used this particular solution more than once. Very fast and easy to understand.

Comment: [Lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog#v400) has deprecated `_.findWhere` in favor of `_.find` with an iteratee so use `_.find(a2, { id: item.id })` instead.

Comment: @GruffBunny why do I get a reference error `ReferenceError: _ is not defined` when attempting to run this code (on node runtime)? Does this require the underscore library? I thought this was just shorthand syntax

Comment: Oh I see, it's using lodash. great

Comment: Using `find` causes the runtime to grow quadratically with the input size. Most other answers below suffer from this problem, too. It is much more efficient (linear time) to create a lookup table by `id` first, for example using `_.groupBy`. The answer by @oriol (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30335130/1166087) takes this approach.

Answer (score 66):

Short ES6 solution

```
const a3 = a1.map(t1 => ({...t1, ...a2.find(t2 => t2.id === t1.id)}))
```

Comment: It doesn't merge ids that are only found in a2

Comment: @Gabriel I think the requirement was to have two lists that share id but have different properties.

Comment: This is not working for multiple cases.

Answer (score 29):

Assuming IDs are strings and the order does not matter, you can

1. Create a hash table.
2. Iterate both arrays and store the data in the hash table, indexed by the ID. If there already is some data with that ID, update it with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (ES6, can be [polyfilled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill)).
3. Get an array with the values of the hash map.

```js
var hash = Object.create(null);
a1.concat(a2).forEach(function(obj) {
    hash[obj.id] = Object.assign(hash[obj.id] || {}, obj);
});
var a3 = Object.keys(hash).map(function(key) {
    return hash[key];
});
```

In ECMAScript6, if the IDs are not necessarily strings, you can use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```
var hash = new Map();
a1.concat(a2).forEach(function(obj) {
    hash.set(obj.id, Object.assign(hash.get(obj.id) || {}, obj))
});
var a3 = Array.from(hash.values());
```

Comment: This solution has better asymptotic complexity (linear) than most other solutions (quadratic). You can write it more concisely using Underscore (or Lodash): `a3 = _.map(_.groupBy(a1.concat(a2), 'id'), arr => _.extend.apply(null, arr));`. Similar answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70474201/1166087.

Answer (score 18):

ES6 simplifies this:

```
let merge = (obj1, obj2) => ({...obj1, ...obj2});
```

Note that repeated keys will be merged, and the value of the second object will prevail and **the repeated value of the first object will be ignored**.

Example:

```
let obj1 = {id: 1, uniqueObj1Key: "uniqueKeyValueObj1", repeatedKey: "obj1Val"};
let obj2 = {id: 1, uniqueObj2Key: "uniqueKeyValueObj2", repeatedKey: "obj2Val"};

merge(obj1, obj2)
// {id: 1, uniqueObj1Key: "uniqueKeyValueObj1", repeatedKey: "obj2Val", uniqueObj2Key: "uniqueKeyValueObj2"}
merge(obj2, obj1)
// {id: 1, uniqueObj2Key: "uniqueKeyValueObj2", repeatedKey: "obj1Val", uniqueObj1Key: "uniqueKeyValueObj1"}
```

## Complete solution (with [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zipWith), not [Underscore](https://underscorejs.org))

```
var a1 = [{ id : 1, name : "test"}, { id : 2, name : "test2"}]
var a2 = [{ id : 1, count : "1"}, {id : 2, count : "2"}]
var merge = (obj1, obj2) => ({...obj1, ...obj2});
_.zipWith(a1, a2, merge)
(2) [{…}, {…}]
   0: {id: 1, name: "test", count: "1"}
   1: {id: 2, name: "test2", count: "2"}
```

If you have an array of arrays to merge you can do it like this:

```
var arrayOfArraysToMerge = [a1, a2, a3, a4]; //a3 and a4 are arrays like a1 and a2 but with different properties and same IDs.
_.zipWith(...arrayOfArraysToMerge, merge)
(2) [{…}, {…}]
   0: {id: 1, name: "test", count: "1", extra1: "val1", extra2: 1}
   1: {id: 2, name: "test2", count: "2", extra1: "val2", extra2: 2}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Please do check the expected result and improve your answer, or remove it.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter I updated the answer to do exactly what the question was asking for, you can check it now :) Anyways I was giving him just a tool to solve his problem but not the full answer so he can learn also a bit without copy/pasting.

Comment: If it's an answer it is an answer not a tool to discover the answer.  What makes your answer better is A. not using a library to achieve the answer and B. explaining your answer so well it teaches people exactly how to answer the question the next time without copy and pasting.

Comment: I don't think this works if the lists aren't in the same order.

Comment: As @user3067860 points out this relies on the list being in the same order This is not to invalidate Alberto's answer just to point out.

Answer (score 12):

[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) version.

```
var a3 = a1.concat(a2).reduce((acc, x) => {
    acc[x.id] = Object.assign(acc[x.id] || {}, x);
    return acc;
}, {});
_.values(a3);
```

I think it's common practice in functional language.

Comment: If you wish to skip using lodash, simple way would be `Object.values` or `Object.keys(a3).map(k => a3[k])`

Answer (score 5):

The lodash implementaiton:

```
var merged = _.map(a1, function(item) {
    return _.assign(item, _.find(a2, ['id', item.id]));
});
```

The result:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"test",
      "count":"1"
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "name":"test2",
      "count":"2"
   }
]
```

Comment: This won't work if a2 has more items in the array than a1

Answer (score 5):

Already there are many great answers, I'll just add another one which is from a real problem I needed to solve yesterday.

I had an array of messages with user ids, and one array of users containing users' names and other details. This is how I managed to add user details to the messages.

```
var messages = [{userId: 2, content: "Salam"}, {userId: 5, content: "Hello"},{userId: 4, content: "Moi"}];
var users = [{id: 2, name: "Grace"}, {id: 4, name: "Janetta"},{id: 5, name: "Sara"}];

var messagesWithUserNames = messages.map((msg)=> {
  var haveEqualId = (user) => user.id === msg.userId
  var userWithEqualId= users.find(haveEqualId)
  return Object.assign({}, msg, userWithEqualId)
})
console.log(messagesWithUserNames)
```

Answer (score 5):

**Vanilla JS solution**

```
const a1 = [{ id : 1, name : "test"}, { id : 2, name : "test2"}]
const a2 = [{ id : 1, count : "1"}, {id : 2, count : "2"}]

const merge = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const temp = []

  arr1.forEach(x => {
    arr2.forEach(y => {
      if (x.id === y.id) {
        temp.push({ ...x, ...y })
      }
    })
  })

  return temp
}

console.log(merge(a1, a2))
```

Comment: This answer is good except it doesn't handle well if one of the array is empty array. It'll return empty array.

Answer (score 4):

Wanted to add this answer which is derived from @daisihi answer above. Main difference is that this uses the spread operator. 
Also, at the end I remove the id because it was not desirable in the first place.

```js
const a3 = [...a1, ...a2].reduce((acc, x) => {
   acc[x.id] = {...acc[x.id] || {}, ...x};
   return acc;
}, {});
```

This part was taken from another post. [removing a property from a list of objects in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46839399/2084798)

```js
const newArray = Object.values(a3).map(({id, ...keepAttrs}) => keepAttrs);
```

Answer (score 3):

Found other solutions failing for some cases, so writing a better one here

```js
const a1 = [{ id : 1, name : "test"}, { id : 2, name : "test2"}]
const a2 = [{ id : 3, count : "3"}, { id : 1, count : "1"}, {id : 2, count : "2"}]


const mergeHelper = new Map(a1.map(x => [x.id, x]));

for (const x of a2) {
    if (mergeHelper.has(x.id)) {
        const item = mergeHelper.get(x.id);
        mergeHelper.set(x.id, {...item, ...x});
    } else {
        mergeHelper.set(x.id, x);
    }
}

const mergedList = [...mergeHelper.values()];
// For sorted array 
// const mergedSortedList = [...mergeHelper.values()].sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);

console.log(mergedList)
```

Using js Map is way faster than other approaches, helps when array length is huge.

Answer (score 2):

A working TypeScript version:

```js
export default class Merge {
  static byKey(a1: any[], a2: any[], key: string) {
    const res = a1.concat(a2).reduce((acc, x) => {
      acc[x[key]] = Object.assign(acc[x[key]] || {}, x);
      return acc;
    }, {});

    return Object.entries(res).map(pair => {
      const [, value] = pair;
      return value;
    });
  }
}

test("Merge", async () => {
  const a1 = [{ id: "1", value: "1" }, { id: "2", value: "2" }];
  const a2 = [{ id: "2", value: "3" }];

  expect(Merge.byKey(a1, a2, "id")).toStrictEqual([
    {
      id: "1",
      value: "1"
    },
    { id: "2", value: "3" }
  ]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var a1 = [{ id : 1, name : "test"}, { id : 2, name : "test2"}]
var a2 = [{ id : 1, count : "1"}, {id : 2, count : "2"}]
let arr3 = a1.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, a2[i]));

console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
const mergeArrayObjects = (arr1: any[], arr2: any[], mergeByKey: string): any[] => {
  const updatedArr = [];
  for (const obj of arr1) {
    const arr1ValueInArr2 = arr2.find(
      a => a[mergeByKey] === obj[mergeByKey],
    );
    if (arr1ValueInArr2) {
      updatedArr.push(Object.assign(obj, arr1ValueInArr2));
    } else {
      updatedArr.push(obj);
    }
  }
  const mergeByKeyValuesInArr1 = arr1.map(a => a[mergeByKey]);
  const remainingObjInArr2 = arr2.filter(a => !mergeByKeyValuesInArr1.includes(a[mergeByKey]) )
  return updatedArr.concat(remainingObjInArr2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple object merging function like this

```
function mergeObject(cake, icing) {
    var icedCake = {}, ingredient;
    for (ingredient in cake)
        icedCake[ingredient] = cake[ingredient];
    for (ingredient in icing)
        icedCake[ingredient] = icing[ingredient];
    return icedCake;
}
```

Next, you need to do use a double-loop to apply it to your data structre

```
var i, j, a3 = a1.slice();
for (i = 0; i < a2.length; ++i)                // for each item in a2
    for (j = 0; i < a3.length; ++i)            // look at items in other array
        if (a2[i]['id'] === a3[j]['id'])       // if matching id
            a3[j] = mergeObject(a3[j], a2[i]); // merge
```

You can also use `mergeObject` as a simple clone, too, by passing one parameter as an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

```
const a3 = a1.map(it1 => {
   it1.test = a2.find(it2 => it2.id === it1.id).test
   return it1
 })
```

Comment: what is the test thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.groupBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy) to do the grouping, and then use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to merge its content.

> It worth noting that [`Object.groupBy` hasn't been widely suported yet](https://caniuse.com/?search=object.groupby). So it might not be a good idea to use in production environment by the time this answer has been posted.

```js
var a1 = [{ id : 1, name : "test"}, { id : 2, name : "test2"}];
var a2 = [{ id : 1, count : "1"}, {id : 2, count : "2"}];

var merged = Object.values(Object.groupBy([...a1, ...a2], 
  ({ id }) => id)).map(e => e.reduce((acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, ...cur }))
);

console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have exactly the same number of items in both array with same ids you could do something like this.

```
const mergedArr = arr1.map((item, i) => {
  if (item.ID === arr2[i].ID) {
    return Object.assign({}, item, arr2[i]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

None of them worked for me. I wrote own:

```
const formatteddata=data.reduce((a1,a2)=>{

for (let t=0; t<a1.length; t++)
    {var id1=a1[t].id
            for (let tt=0; tt<a2.length; tt++)
                {var id2=a2[tt].id
                    if(id1==date2)
                      {a1[t]={...a1[t],...a2[tt]}}
                }
    }
return a1

})
```

works with any amount of arrays of objects in arrays, with varying length and not always coinsciding dates

Comment: again, this doesn't answer the question

Comment: This doesn't work at all. What is `data`? Why is there `date2`? What's even the point of this improper use of `reduce`? This code is just nonsense.