# Sails: how to properly join two tables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, many-to-many, sails.js, waterline

I have two models: **Node** and **NodeMessage**. They share a many-to-many relationship (There are messages in the nodes and a message can be in more than one node)

*Node*

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    [...]

    // Messages within the node
    messages:  {
        collection: 'NodeMessage',
        via: 'nodes'
    },

    [...]
  }
```

*NodeMessage*

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    [...]

    // Nodes where this message appear
    nodes: {
        collection: 'Node',
        via: 'messages'
    },

    // Users who liked this message
    likes: {
        collection: 'User',
        via: 'likes'
    }

    [...]
  }
}
```

It's a basic Many-to-Many sails relationship. 
Now I want to get all the messages contained in a group of Nodes. I mean, lets take 1 node and its 8 neighbors (9 in total): I want to get all the messages of these nodes.

I have been able to retrieve these messages by querying the nodes and using **populate** (*messages*), but I need to populate the *likes* attribute of these messages, which I can't.

The solution I am considering is to get all the IDs of these not populated messages and make another query so as to get them, but this would mean 2 queries and that wouldn't make me happy :(

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript merging objects by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480008/javascript-merging-objects-by-id)

Comment: this is about a node.js framework: http://sailsjs.org/