# Merging two arrays in order based on id

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I have 2 array of objects:

```
var parents = [
  { id: 77777, data: {}},
  { id: 88888, data: {}},
  { id: 99999, data: {}}
]


var children = [
  {
    belongTo: 77777,
    data: [
      { id: 111, data: {}},
      { id: 222, data: {}}
    ]},
  {
    belongTo: 99999,
    data: [
      { id: 333, data: {}}
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to merge the parents and children into:

```
var all = [
  { id: 77777, data: {}},
  { id: 111, data: {}},
  { id: 222, data: {}},
  { id: 88888, data: {}},
  { id: 99999, data: {}},
  { id: 333, data: {}}
]
```

]

I have been trying to use split or merge them together and then flatten but it was always very complicated.

**What will be the easiest way to achieve that merge?**

**My complicated way(which doesn't work)**:

```
children.map(function(child) {
  var parentIndex = parents.map(function(x) {return x.id}).indexOf(child.id)

  parents.splice(parentIndex + 1, 0, child.data)
})

[].concat.apply([], parents)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480008/javascript-merging-objects-by-id

Comment: ups q wasn't liked:( didnt know how to word it tho

Comment: not a duplicate of suggested q I don't need to merge object but merge the arrays in order based on id

Comment: @Kocur4d Please show your attempts toward solving the problem

Answer (score 3):

You just need some nested loops to get it:
http://jsfiddle.net/hpfgqc4m/2/

```
var parents = [
  { 
    id: 77777,
    data: {}
  },
  { 
    id: 88888,
    data: {}
  },
  { 
    id: 99999,
    data: {}
  }
]


var children = [
  {
    belongTo: 77777,
    data: [{
      id: 111,
      data: {}
    },
    {
      id: 222,
      data: {}
    }]
  },
  {
    belongTo: 99999,
    data: [{
      id: 333,
      data: {}
    }]
  }
]
var all = [];
parents.forEach(function(e, k) {
    all.push(e);
    children.forEach(function(el, key) {
        if (el.belongTo == e.id) {
            el.data.forEach(function(element) {
                all.push(element);            
            });                
        }
    });
});
console.log(all);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var parents = [{
    id: 77777,
    data: {}
}, {
    id: 88888,
    data: {}
}, {
    id: 99999,
    data: {}
}];

var children = [{
    belongTo: 77777,
    data: [{
        id: 111,
        data: {}
    }, {
        id: 222,
        data: {}
    }]
}, {
    belongTo: 99999,
    data: [{
        id: 333,
        data: {}
    }]
}];

function merge(parents, children) {
  var parentsLen = parents.length,
      childLen = children.length,
      i, j,
      result = [];
  
  for (i = 0; i < parentsLen; i++) { 
    result.push(parents[i]);
    
    for (j = 0; j < childLen; j++) {
      if (parents[i].id === children[j].belongTo) {
        result = result.concat(children[j].data);
      }
    };
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(merge(parents, children));
```

Fix for your version

```js
var parents = [{
    id: 77777,
    data: {}
}, {
    id: 88888,
    data: {}
}, {
    id: 99999,
    data: {}
}];

var children = [{
    belongTo: 77777,
    data: [{
        id: 111,
        data: {}
    }, {
        id: 222,
        data: {}
    }]
}, {
    belongTo: 99999,
    data: [{
        id: 333,
        data: {}
    }]
}];

children.forEach(function(child) {
  var parentIndex = parents.map(function(x) {return x.id}).indexOf(child.id);
  parents.splice(parentIndex + 1, 0, child.data)
})

parents = [].concat.apply([], parents)

console.log(parents);
```

Comment: Hi sorry, got hold up with something. Yes it works fine, both solution - so thank you guys. I will check later on to see my initial splice way with a bit of es6 sugar would make it more pretty

Answer (score 0):

Using [Higher Order Functions](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html) and a bit of [ES6](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/):

```
let merged = parents.map((parent) => {
  let child = children.filter((child) => child.belongTo == parent.id)
  let data = child.length > 0 ? child[0].data : []
  return [parent].concat(data)
})

console.log([].concat(...merged))
```

Can this be refactored further?