# JavaScript - merge two arrays of objects and de-duplicate based on property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I want to **update** (replace) the objects in my array with the objects in another array. Each object has the same structure. e.g.

```
var origArr = [
  {name: 'Trump', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'Kasich', isRunning: true}
];
var updatingArr = [
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: false},
  {name: 'Kasich', isRunning: false}
];
// desired result:
NEWArr = [
  {name: 'Trump', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: false},
  {name: 'Kasich', isRunning: false}
];
```

I've tried concat() & Underscore's `_.uniq` function, but it always dumps the newer object & returns, essentially, the original array.

Is there a way to overwrite (replace) `origArr` with the objects in `updatingArr` -- matching on the `name` property?

Comment: Is that what you are meaning? https://jsfiddle.net/4p98w3su/ not sure I understood the question.

Comment: All good answers here; I like yours the best, using splice. If you want to convert this to an Answer, I'll mark as Accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a double for loop and splice you can do it like so:

```
for(var i = 0, l = origArr.length; i < l; i++) {
    for(var j = 0, ll = updatingArr.length; j < ll; j++) {
        if(origArr[i].name === updatingArr[j].name) {
            origArr.splice(i, 1, updatingArr[j]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4p98w3su/1/)

Comment: with this being the accepted answer. How to achieve if from updatingArr id is not existing on the origArr. Just push the updatingArr elements to origArr.

Answer (score 21):

I came here looking for exactly this, saw @Gruff Bunny 's technique and wondered if 'lodash' wouldn't perhaps be a superior option even to 'underscore'?

Lo and behold :

```
let result = _.unionBy(updatingArr, origArr, 'name');
```

Comment: While Underscore is much smaller than Lodash, you can still get the same result in a single line using `concat`, `groupBy`, `map` and `last`. You can also add `unionBy` to Underscore in just five lines of code. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70474201/1166087).

Answer (score 10):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in combination with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var origArr = [{ name: 'Trump', isRunning: true }, { name: 'Cruz', isRunning: true }, { name: 'Kasich', isRunning: true }],
    updatingArr = [{ name: 'Cruz', isRunning: false }, { name: 'Kasich', isRunning: false }],
    NEWArr = origArr.map(function (a) {
        return this[a.name] || a;
    }, updatingArr.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.name] = a;
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null)));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(NEWArr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

**UPDATE 2022**

Using an object with `name` as hash and mapping the original array by taking the update from hash table or the original object.

```js
const
    origArr = [{ name: 'Trump', isRunning: true }, { name: 'Cruz', isRunning: true }, { name: 'Kasich', isRunning: true }],
    updatingArr = [{ name: 'Cruz', isRunning: false }, { name: 'Kasich', isRunning: false }],
    updates = Object.fromEntries(updatingArr.map(o => [o.name, o])),
    result = origArr.map(o => updates[o.name] || o);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another approach by using [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

This approach works for objects who are only in the updating array as well.

```js
const
    origArr = [{ name: 'Trump', isRunning: true }, { name: 'Cruz', isRunning: true }, { name: 'Kasich', isRunning: true }],
    updatingArr = [{ name: 'Cruz', isRunning: false }, { name: 'Kasich', isRunning: false }],
    result = Array.from([...origArr, ...updatingArr]
        .reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.name, o), new Map)
        .values()
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: i need some explainer for this, please... :/

Comment: @A.Rabus, this code is acutally using a hash table for udate values and maps either the updates values or the original value. actually, i would separate the two steps into two parts and do not use `this` anymore.

Comment: How to achieve if from updatingArr id is not existing on the origArr. Just push the updatingArr elements to origArr

Comment: This is amazing! Congratulations!

Answer (score 3):

```
const origArr = [
  {name: 'Trump', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'Kasich', isRunning: true}
];

const updatingArr = [
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: false},
  {name: 'Kasich', isRunning: false}
];

let hash = {};

for(let i of origArr.concat(updatingArr)) {
  if(!hash[i]) {
    hash[i.name] = i;
  }
}

let newArr = [];

for(let i in hash) {
  newArr.push(hash[i])
}

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hash which gives the index by name, and `Object.assign` to update.

```
var hash = origArr.reduce(function(hash, obj, index) {
  hash[obj.name] = index;
  return hash;
}, Object.create(null));
for(var obj of updatingArr) {
  Object.assign(origArr[hash[obj.name]], obj);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give this a try.

```
var origArr = [
  {name: 'Trump', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'Kasich', isRunning: true}
];
var updatingArr = [
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: false},
  {name: 'Kasich', isRunning: false}
];

var origLength = origArr.length;
var updatingLength = updatingArr.length;

//Traverse the original array and replace only if the second array also has the same value
for(i = origLength-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for(j = updatingLength -1; j >= 0; j--) {
    if(origArr[i].name === updatingArr[j].name) {
        origArr[i] = updatingArr[j];
    }
  }
}

console.log(origArr);
```

Comment: traversal is done in the reverse order since it is least time consuming, according to tests conducted by jspref

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using underscore:

```
var result = _.map(origArr, function(orig){
    return _.extend(orig, _.findWhere(updatingArr, {name: orig.name}));
});
```

Comment: More compact and efficient solution using Underscore, which also adds new entries on update: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70474201/1166087

Answer (score 2):

This version lets you define the `selector` that defines an object as duplicate.

- forEach iterates over the new data
- findIndex returns an index `>= 0` if two selectors are equal. If none are equal, it returns `-1`
- If there is a duplicate, we use slice to replace the original by the new.
- If there's no duplicate, we push it into the original array.

```js
const origArr = [
  {name: 'Trump', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'Kasich', isRunning: true}
];

const updatingArr = [
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: false},
  {name: 'Kasich', isRunning: false}
];

const mergeArrayOfObjects = (original, newdata, selector = 'key') => {
 newdata.forEach(dat => {
  const foundIndex = original.findIndex(ori => ori[selector] == dat[selector]);
  if (foundIndex >= 0) original.splice(foundIndex, 1, dat);
        else original.push(dat);
 });

 return original;
};

const result = mergeArrayOfObjects(origArr, updatingArr, "name")
console.log('RESULT -->', result)
```

Answer (score 2):

In ES6 you can use the object [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) like this...

```
let map = new Map();
let origArr = [
  {name: 'Trump', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'Kasich', isRunning: true}
];
let updatingArr = [
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: false},
  {name: 'Kasich', isRunning: false}
];

// Concating arrays with duplicates
let NEWArr = origArr.concat(updatingArr);

// Removing duplicates items
NEWArr.forEach(item => {
  if(!map.has(item.name)){
    map.set(item.name, item);
  }
});

Array.from(map.values());
```

**Remember: the Map object need in unique key, in this case I used the `name`.**

Comment: Thx, this is short and clean!

Comment: I do not think this is correct. Because the result is `{name: 'Trump', isRunning: true}, {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: true}, {name: 'Kasich', isRunning: true}` which I think is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you need:

```js
var origArr = [
  {name: 'Trump', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'Kasich', isRunning: true}
];

var updatingArr = [
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: false},
  {name: 'Kasich', isRunning: false}
];

for (var i = 0; i < updatingArr.length; ++i) {
  var updateItem = updatingArr[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < origArr.length; ++j) {
    var origItem = origArr[j];
    if (origItem.name == updateItem.name) {
      origItem.isRunning = updateItem.isRunning;
      break;    
    }
  }
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(origArr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as @gevorg answer, but you may want to also add a new object to the original array if no matches are found.

```
let combinedEvents = origEvents;
for(let i =0; i< newEvents.length; i++){
  let newEvent = newEvents[i];
  for(let j =0; j< origEvents.length; j++){
    let origEvent = origEvents[j];
    if(newEvent.events_id == origEvent.events_id){
      combinedEvents.splice(j,1, newEvent);
      break;
    } else if(j === origEvents.length - 1){
      combinedEvents.push(newEvent);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Backbone](https://backbonejs.org)'s collections are well equipped for scenarios like this one.

First, we define a model type that knows to look for the `name` property:

```js
import { Model } from 'backbone';

const President = Model.extend({ idAttribute: 'name' });
```

Then, we put the initial array in a collection that uses the above model:

```js
import { Collection } from 'backbone';

const presidents = new Collection(origArr, { model: President });
```

Now, we can run `presidents.set` as often as we want, and it will merge the new representation with the old values:

```js
presidents.set(updateArr);

presidents.get('Cruz').get('isRunning'); // false
presidents.toJSON(); // NEWArr
```

Putting it all together in a runnable snippet:

```js
const { Model, Collection } = Backbone;

const President = Model.extend({ idAttribute: 'name' });

const presidents = new Collection([
  {name: 'Trump', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'Kasich', isRunning: true}
], { model: President });

presidents.set([
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: false},
  {name: 'Kasich', isRunning: false}
]);

console.log(presidents.get('Cruz').get('isRunning'));
console.log(presidents.toJSON());
```

```html
<script src="https://underscorejs.org/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Single-line pure Underscore solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70474201/1166087

Answer (score 0):

While Underscore does not have a direct equivalent to Lodash's `unionBy`, you can still get the same result in an efficient oneliner using `concat`, `groupBy`, `map` and `last`:

```js
import { groupBy, map, last } from 'underscore';

var NEWArr = map(groupBy(origArr.concat(updateArr), 'name'), last);
```

Equivalent, slightly lengthier but cleaner notation using `chain`:

```js
import { chain } from 'underscore';

var NEWArr = chain(origArr).concat(updateArr).groupBy('name').map(last).value();
```

In fact, you can define your own `unionBy` using the above recipe and add it to Underscore yourself:

```js
import _, { groupBy, map, first } from 'underscore';

function unionBy(...args) {
    const iteratee = _.iteratee(args.pop());
    const candidates = [].concat.apply(null, args);
    return map(groupBy(candidates, iteratee), first);
}

_.mixin({ unionBy }); // unionBy can now be used in chaining
```

Note that we are now using `first` instead of `last`, because the semantics of Lodash's `unionBy` dictate that the first occurrence wins.

Comment: While not asked in the original question, Backbone arguably has the best solution for updating data. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70474027/1166087.

Answer (score -2):

Try this approach with ES-6 **Set** Data Structure:
`const result = [...new Set([...origArr, ...updatingArr])]`

Comment: This will only work for the flat lists. Won't work for this scenario.