# Replacing content of array on the basis of property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I am working on an angular application. I have two arrays as follows:

```js
array1 = [
  {
    Name: "Jack",
    Id: "1",
    Location: "UK"
  },
  {
    Name: "Rose",
    Id: "2",
    Location: "USA"
  },
  {
    Name: "Mary",
    Id: "3",
    Location: "India"
  }
];

array2 = [
  {
    Name: "Raj",
    Id: "5",
    Location: "UK"
  },
  {
    Name: "John",
    Id: "2",
    Location: "Germany"
  },
  {
    Name: "Maria",
    Id: "3",
    Location: "Canada"
  }
];
```

I want a resultant array such that If "Id" of any element of array1 matches "Id" of any element in array2, then whole data for that particular "Id" should be replaced in array2. So my resulArray will look as follows:

```js
resultArray = [
  {
    Name: "Raj",
    Id: "5",
    Location: "UK"
  },
  {
    Name: "Rose",
    Id: "2",
    Location: "USA"
  },
  {
    Name: "Mary",
    Id: "3",
    Location: "India"
  }
];
```

So Id= 2 and Id =3 of array 1 matches in array2, so data of Id=2 and Id=3 in array2 are replaced by that of array1. How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585309/replacing-objects-in-array)

Comment: I think you can just replace your objects in array by using `map`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `map` and `find` here. You can put an `OR` condition that if value is present in `array1` if so then will pick the object from `array1` otherwise the `current object` will be chosen.

```js
var array2=[ { "Name": "Raj", "Id": "5", "Location": "UK" }, { "Name": "John", "Id": "2", "Location": "Germany" }, { "Name": "Maria", "Id": "3", "Location": "Canada" }];

var array1= [{ "Name": "Jack", "Id": "1", "Location": "UK"},{ "Name": "Rose", "Id": "2", "Location": "USA"},{ "Name": "Mary", "Id": "3", "Location": "India"}];

var result = array2.map(p=>(array1.find(k=>k.Id==p.Id) || p));

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: why these three dots before array1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and `find` function for your requirement

```
array2.reduce((acc, c) => {
  var existed = array1.find(a=>a.Id == c.Id);
  if(existed){
     c.Name = existed.Name;
  }
  return c;
}, [])
```

```js
var array1= [
{
   "Name": "Jack",
   "Id": "1",
   "Location": "UK"
},
{
   "Name": "Rose",
   "Id": "2",
    "Location": "USA"
},
{
   "Name": "Mary",
   "Id": "3",
   "Location": "India"
}
]

var array2=[
 {
       "Name": "Raj",
       "Id": "5",
       "Location": "UK"
    },
    {
       "Name": "John",
       "Id": "2",
        "Location": "Germany"
    },
    {
       "Name": "Maria",
       "Id": "3",
       "Location": "Canada"
    }
];


array2.reduce((acc, c) => {
  var existed = array1.find(a=>a.Id == c.Id);
  if(existed){
     c.Name = existed.Name;
  }
  return c;
}, [])

console.log(array2)
```