# How can I remove the duplicate elements from this array of objects using find method?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I want to push the elements of arr2 into arr1 but it should not duplicate the elements

```
let arr = [{obj: "ABC"},{obj: "XYZ"},{obj: "LMN"}]
const arr2 = [{obj: "ABC"},{obj: "MNO"}]
 
arr2.forEach(j => {
           arr.find((e =>{
              if(j.obj !== e.obj){
                arr.push({ obj: `${j.obj}|` });
              }
           }))
```

Comment: `const found = arr.find((e => e.obj === j.obj); if (found) push`

Comment: another approach would be to convert arr1 values to a set and foreach arr2 checking if set has value and push if it doesnt

Comment: you actually want to *avoid* `find` because nesting two linear operations (`forEach` and `find`) results in a quadratic space-time complexity. see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56894824/633183) for a guide on compound data equality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - merge two arrays of objects and de-duplicate based on property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057746/javascript-merge-two-arrays-of-objects-and-de-duplicate-based-on-property-valu)

Answer (score 1):

The find method is actually not the best way to go about this answer.
To push elements from arr2 into arr without duplicating, you can check if the object already exists in arr before pushing it. Here's an updated version:

```js
let arr = [{ obj: "ABC" }, { obj: "XYZ" }, { obj: "LMN" }];
const arr2 = [{ obj: "ABC" }, { obj: "MNO" }];

arr2.forEach((j) => {
  // Check if the object is not already in arr
  if (!arr.some((e) => e.obj === j.obj)) {
    arr.push({ obj: j.obj });
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [new Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set) which by nature does not allows to [contain duplicate values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).
There's a caveat though, since we cannot compare two different instances of an Object (even if the contents are the same) - those objects must first be stringified in order for the Set *values uniqueness* magic to kick in:

```js
const a1 = [{ obj: "ABC" }, { obj: "XYZ" }, { obj: "LMN" }];
const a2 = [{ obj: "ABC" }, { obj: "MNO" }];

const ob2st = o => JSON.stringify(o);
const st2ob = s => JSON.parse(s);

const mergedSet = new Set([...a1.map(ob2st), ...a2.map(ob2st)]);
const a3 = [...mergedSet].map(st2ob);

console.log(a3);
```

also important to notice is that the newly created objects inside our new `a3` array - modifying their property values, will no longer be reflected in the original `a1` and `a2` objects. This practice helps to maintain data integrity.