# Javascript: merge to array of objects (SQL style join)

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have two arrays of objects:

```
array1 = [{id : 1, pop: 4000}, etc.]
array2 = [{id : 1, size: 2000}, etc.]
```

I would like to merge the two arrays (on id) for:

```
merged = [{id :1, pop: 4000, size: 2000}, etc.]
```

I saw `extend` and other options like `concat` but nothing quite what I was going for

Comment: do you want to merge the objects based on it's id?

Comment: @andrejunges yes, sorry that was not clear

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480008/javascript-merging-objects-by-id

Answer (score 0):

No need for underscore, you can use Object.assign:

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/pesuju/2/edit?js,console)

```
var array1 = [{id : 1, pop: 4000}, {id : 2, pop: 4000}];

var array2 = [{id : 1, size: 2000}, {id : 1, blah: 4000}, {id : 2, size: 4000}];

var merged = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  var obj = {};
   for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
     if (array1[i].id === array2[j].id) {
       obj = Object.assign(obj, array1[i], array2[j]);
       merged.push(obj);
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With lodash:

```
result = _(array1)
     .concat(array2)
     .groupBy('id')
     .map(_.spread(_.extend))
     .value();
```

Unlike map+find solutions, this is linear. Note that it's a "full outer" join, so the result will include non-matching elements from both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Using [underscore JS](http://underscorejs.org/) :

```
var array1 = [{ id: 1, pop: 4000 }, { id: 2, pop: 7000 }];

  var array2 = [{ id: 1, pop: 5000 }, { id: 2, pop: 6000 }];

var merge = _.map(array1, function(curr){

    return _.extend(curr, _.findWhere(array2, { id: curr.id })); });
```

I think it should work..

Answer (score 0):

A solution in plain Javascript with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and  [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object.keys) and an object for the reference to the array elements.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 1, pop: 4000 }, { id: 2, pop: 2000 }],
    array2 = [{ id: 1, size: 2000 }, { id: 2, size: 0 }],
    merged = [];

function getMerged(array1, array2) {
    function iter(a) {
        if (!obj[a.id]) {
            obj[a.id] = { id: a.id };
            result.push(obj[a.id]);
        }
        Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
            if (k !== 'id') {
                obj[a.id][k] = a[k];
            }
        });
    }

    var result = [],
        obj = Object.create(null);

    array1.forEach(iter);
    array2.forEach(iter);
    return result;
}

console.log(getMerged(array1, array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.map`, `_.extend` and `_.findWhere` in **[Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)**.

*Example:*

```js
const array1 = [{
  "id": 1,
  "pop": 400
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "pop": 2000
}];
const array2 = [{
  "id": 1,
  "size": 5000
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "size": 500
}];


const mergeById = (a, b) => a.map(x => _.extend(x, _.findWhere(b, {"id": x.id})));

console.log(mergeById(array1, array2));

/* RESULT:

 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "pop": 400,
    "size": 5000
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "pop": 2000,
    "size": 500
  }
]
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```