# JS/Es6 how to merge two arrays and override values in their objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Lets say I have an array like this

```
let arrayOne = [{text="one", value=0},{text="two", value=0}]
let arrayTwo = [{text="two", value=5}]
```

So `arrayOne` will always the entire set of objects I want, but all the values will be 0. `arrayTwo` will have a subset of this array but will always have a value set. What I want is as follows, if `arrayTwo` objects exists in `arrayOne` then copy the value to the `arrayOne` object.

So in the end  I would want

```
let arrayOne = [{text="one", value=0},{text="two", value=5}]
```

I did something like this, but I feel I am missing some es6 magic.

```
for (let orig of arrayOne) {
                arrayTwo.find(item => {
                    if (item.value == orig.value) {
                        Object.assign(orig, item);
                    }
                })
            }
```

Comment: *"I feel I am missing some es6 magic"* not really, but that's not the correct use of `find`. The callback should return `true` or `false`, `.find` will then return the matching value or `null`. The way you use it, you should use `forEach`. Also, iterating over `arrayTwo` would probably make more sense.

Comment: @Felix gotcha thanks that good feedback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is

```
arrayOne = arrayOne.map(item1 => {
  return Object.assign(item1, arrayTwo.find(item2 => {
    return item1.text === item2.text
  }))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered something similar in [JavaScript merging objects by id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30335130/1529630)

However, since you want to update one of the initial arrays, and you say the other one is a subset, you can improve it to

```js
let arrayOne = [{text:"one", value:0},{text:"two", value:0}]
let arrayTwo = [{text:"two", value:5}]
var hash = Object.create(null);
arrayOne.forEach(obj => hash[obj.text] = obj);
arrayTwo.forEach(obj => Object.assign(hash[obj.text], obj));
console.log(arrayOne);
```

The cost is only linear on average, `O(arrayOne.length)` to fill the hash and `O(arrayTwo.length)` for the assignments, assuming few properties for each object.