# Merge Objects in Two Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Trying to work out the most performant way to merge objects from two arrays (that share an id) into a brand new array of the same length of the original two arrays.

For example:

```
// Merge these two arrays
const arrayOne = [
  { id: 34560, name: "John" },
  { id: 23123, name: "Jake" },
  { id: 11023, name: "Peter" },
  { id: 29221, name: "Sara" }
];

const arrayTwo = [
  { id: 34560, age: 24 },
  { id: 23123, age: 30 },
  { id: 11023, age: 19 },
  { id: 29221, age: 20 }
];

// Into this array
const merged = [
  { id: 34560, name: "John", age: 24 },
  { id: 23123, name: "Jake", age: 30 },
  { id: 11023, name: "Peter", age: 19 },
  { id: 29221, name: "Sara", age: 20 }
];
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
const mergedArray = [];

arrayOne.forEach(x => {
  arrayTwo.forEach(y => {
    if (x.id === y.id) {
      mergedArray.push(Object.assign(x, y));
    }
  })
})
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably a better question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since it is about optimizing working code

Comment: Would be far more performant to iterate one array first and add it's ID to a temporary object as property, then you would only loop the other array once also and check if that id property exists in temp object

Comment: @Gothdo - at least find something which is an actual duplicate of this question: 
1 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items, 2 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480008/javascript-merging-objects-by-id

Comment: Vanilla js example https://jsfiddle.net/svfam112/

Comment: @charlietfl Elegant stuff! Submit this as an answer and I'll happily accept it.