# Merging of two arrays with conditions without using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am facing problem to merge the two arrays. I have two arrays of objects first is prev having old values and another with updated values. I would like to have result array with all the objects of prev array with its updated value in array next, and also have objects in next array.

Example:

```
var prev = [{id: 1, val: 'abc'}, {id: 2, val: 'pqr'}];
var next = [{id: 1, val: 'nextVal'}, {id: 3, val: 'xyz'}];
```

expected

```
mergeOutput = [
  {id: 1, val: 'nextVal'}, // value is updated 
  {id: 2, val: 'pqr'}, 
  {id: 3, val: 'xyz'}
]
```

Note: Array order do not matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Map()` to merge array.

```js
var prev = [{id: 1, val: 'abc'}, {id: 2, val: 'pqr'}];
var next = [{id: 1, val: 'nextVal'}, {id: 3, val: 'xyz'}];

var hash = new Map();
prev.concat(next).forEach(function(obj) {
    hash.set(obj.id, Object.assign(hash.get(obj.id) || {}, obj))
});

var mergedArray = Array.from(hash.values());
console.log(mergedArray);
```

Source : [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30335130/4758494)