# Is there a ways to combine objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some data cleaning in Javascript, and I was wondering if there is a way to combine objects based on a common ID.

Given the following:

```
{"subject":"Hadji Singh","predicate":"nameOfUser","id":"3f540200-58b9-40a5-91c2-faafec75216f"}
{"subject":"Race Roger Bannon","predicate":"nameOfUser","id":"41376a49-34ee-4ed8-b5f5-3f8c92b107f8"}
{"subject":"Jessie Bannon","predicate":"nameOfUser","id":"9575cf33-8992-4763-81bb-fc640ffa3545"}
{"subject":"Adventurer","predicate":"departmentOfUser","id":"3f540200-58b9-40a5-91c2-faafec75216f"}
{"subject":"Bodyguard","predicate":"departmentOfUser","id":"41376a49-34ee-4ed8-b5f5-3f8c92b107f8"}
{"subject":"Adventurer","predicate":"departmentOfUser","id":"9575cf33-8992-4763-81bb-fc640ffa3545"}
```

Is there a way to turn it into something like this?

```
[{id:3f540200-58b9-40a5-91c2-faafec75216f, name:Hadji Singh, department:Adventurer},
{id:9575cf33-8992-4763-81bb-fc640ffa3545, name:Jessie Bannon, department:Adventurer},
{id:41376a49-34ee-4ed8-b5f5-3f8c92b107f8, name:Race Bannon, department:Bodyguard}]
```

I'm thinking of two for loops (maybe) and a lot of if's, but perhaps there's some way I'm missing.

I'm using node.js, if that means anything. Perhaps there's a module that can help?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really help us to figure out the issue with your code. Thanks!

Comment: Use the `id` as a `HashMap` key and do recursive [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)s.  You'll have to set rules for precendence though.  Please provide more details and maybe some attempts.

Comment: Using Underscore -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480008/javascript-merging-objects-by-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reduce` method of an array:

```
let a = [{"subject":"Hadji Singh","predicate":"nameOfUser","id":"3f540200-58b9-40a5-91c2-faafec75216f"},
{"subject":"Race Roger Bannon","predicate":"nameOfUser","id":"41376a49-34ee-4ed8-b5f5-3f8c92b107f8"},
{"subject":"Jessie Bannon","predicate":"nameOfUser","id":"9575cf33-8992-4763-81bb-fc640ffa3545"},
{"subject":"Adventurer","predicate":"departmentOfUser","id":"3f540200-58b9-40a5-91c2-faafec75216f"},
{"subject":"Bodyguard","predicate":"departmentOfUser","id":"41376a49-34ee-4ed8-b5f5-3f8c92b107f8"},
{"subject":"Adventurer","predicate":"departmentOfUser","id":"9575cf33-8992-4763-81bb-fc640ffa3545"}]

let b = a.reduce((acc, val) => {
  let id = val.id
  let idx = acc.findIndex((e) => e.id == id);
  let subj = { id: id }
  let predicate = val['predicate'].split('OfUser')[0]
  subj[predicate] = val['subject']
  if (-1 == idx) {
    acc.push(subj);
  } else {
    acc[idx] = Object.assign(acc[idx], subj);
  }
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(b);

//[ { id: '3f540200-58b9-40a5-91c2-faafec75216f',
//    name: 'Hadji Singh',
//    department: 'Adventurer' },
//  { id: '41376a49-34ee-4ed8-b5f5-3f8c92b107f8',
//    name: 'Race Roger Bannon',
//    department: 'Bodyguard' },
//  { id: '9575cf33-8992-4763-81bb-fc640ffa3545',
//    name: 'Jessie Bannon',
//    department: 'Adventurer' } ]
```