# How to join two arrays conditionally

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays that I want to join conditionally:

```
aData = [ { id: 1, title: `bla`}, { id: 2, title: `la`}, { id: 3, title: `lala`} ]
bData = [ { id: 1, description: `bla`} ]
```

In the first case I want to be able to get only matching result (`aData+bData`) with merged properties

```
matchingIdsResult = [ { id: 1, title: `bla`, description: `bla` } ]
```

IN the second case I want the unmatching result - just objects from `aData` with ids that didn't ocour in `bData`:

```
unmathingIdsResult = [ { id: 2, title: `la`}, { id: 3, title: `lala`} ]
```

I was playing with `.map` and `.reduce` and achieve this so far:

```
const data: any = aData.concat(bData).reduce((acc, x) => {
    acc[x.id] = Object.assign(acc[x.id] || {}, x);
    return acc;
}, {});
```

However in that case I do get all `aData` objects merged with matching `bData` properties so far which is not really what I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript merging objects by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480008/javascript-merging-objects-by-id)

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: What is wrong with good old Loops? Why you need to have a built-in Array method for it?

Answer (score 1):

Create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) by `id` from `bData`. Iterate `aData` with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). If an object `id` is in the `bDataMap` push the combined object into the 1st sub array. If not, to the 2nd. Get the `matchingIdsResult` and `unmatchingIdsResult` by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) the results of the reduce:

```js
const aData = [{"id":1,"title":"bla"},{"id":2,"title":"la"},{"id":3,"title":"lala"}];
const bData = [{"id":1,"description":"bla"}];

const bDataMap = new Map(bData.map((o) => [o.id, o]));

const [matchingIdsResult, unmatchingIdsResult] = aData.reduce((r, o) => {
  if(bDataMap.has(o.id)) r[0].push(Object.assign({}, o, bDataMap.get(o.id)));
  else r[1].push(o);
  
  return r;
}, [[], []]);
  
console.log(matchingIdsResult);
console.log(unmatchingIdsResult);
```

If you want to skip the creation of `bDataMap`, you can use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). The complexity would become O(n * m) instead of o(n + m) with the Map (n - aData.length, m - bData.length), but that might be negligible with small arrays:

```js
const aData = [{"id":1,"title":"bla"},{"id":2,"title":"la"},{"id":3,"title":"lala"}];
const bData = [{"id":1,"description":"bla"}];

const [matchingIdsResult, unmatchingIdsResult] = aData.reduce((r, o) => {
  const match = bData.find(({ id }) => id === o.id);

  if(match) r[0].push(Object.assign({}, o, match));
  else r[1].push(o);
  
  return r;
}, [[], []]);
  
console.log(matchingIdsResult);
console.log(unmatchingIdsResult);
```

Comment: will that cover both cases?

Comment: @sreginogemoh - Now it does   :)

Answer (score 1):

You could take the first array as unmatching start values and check the second and either split matching objects or push to unmatching array.

```js
var aData = [{ id: 1, title: 'bla' }, { id: 2, title: 'la' }, { id: 3, title: 'lala' }],
    bData = [{ id: 1, description: 'bla' }],
    unmatching = aData,
    matching = [];

bData.forEach(o => {
    var index = unmatching.findIndex(({ id }) => o.id = id);
    if (index === -1) {
        unmatching.push(o);
    } else {
        matching.push(Object.assign({}, unmatching.splice(index, 1)[0], o));
    }
});

console.log(matching);
console.log(unmatching);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a map of unmatched and matched checking simply if `id` exists or not.

And when you've got two separate awways of `matched` and `unmatched`, simply merge the `matched` array (on the basis of `ID`) with the other array containing the data.

```js
aData = [ { id: 1, title: `bla`}, { id: 2, title: `la`}, { id: 3, title: `lala`} ]
bData = [ { id: 1, description: `bla`} ];
var unmatched = [],
   matched = [];
aData.every(x=> bData.map(e=> e.id).includes(x.id) ? matched.push(x) : unmatched.push(x))
matched = matched.map(x=> Object.assign(x, bData.find(e=> e.id ===x.id )))
console.log("Matched " , matched)

console.log("Un matched", unmatched)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```