# How to combine array values in React Redux like SQL joins with same id?

Tags: reactjs, redux

const initialState = {

```
booksData: [
{"Code":"BK01","price":"5"},
{"code":"BK02","price":"30"},
] 
author: [
{"Code":"BK01","name":"Ravi"},
{"code":"BK02","name":"Suresh"},
]
```

};

combinedBooksData: [

```
{"Code":"BK01","price":"10","name":"Ravi"},
{"code":"BK02","price":"25","name":"Suresh"},
```

]

Comment: Hi Sirushti, could you give a little more information? Just posting code isn't really helpful. what have you tried, and what is the expected result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript merging objects by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480008/javascript-merging-objects-by-id)

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
var mergedList = _.map(initialState.booksData, function(item){
    return _.extend(item, _.findIndex(initialState.author, { id: item.Code }));
});
```