# Compare two arrays of objects and assign value

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I have two object arrays:

```
 let arr1 = [{id: 100, quantity: 2, grp: 1A},{...},{...}, ...],

 let arr2 = [{id: 100, color: "#000"},{...},{...}, ...],
```

arr2 contains objects with the id and color for every object from arr1.

My question is: How can I loop through both object arrays and add the color property of arr2 to the according object in arr1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript merging objects by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480008/javascript-merging-objects-by-id)

Answer (score 1):

Use `forEach` to loop over `arr1`, and inside that function, use `filter` to find the item of `arr2` that is a match for the current item in `arr1`:

```
arr1.forEach(item=>item.color = arr2.filter(colorObj=>colorObj.id===item.id)[0].color)
```

Or, slightly more readably:

```
arr1.forEach(item=>{
    var matchingColorObj = arr2.filter(colorObj=>colorObj.id===item.id)[0];
    item.color = matchingColorObj.color;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to search through `arr1` for every item of `arr2` (making an O(n²) solution), you could make a lookup object for `arr1` keyed to `id`. Then you can simply loop through `arr2` merging the object found by looking it up. This will be more efficient if you have larger arrays.

```js
let arr1 = [{id: 100, quantity: 2, grp: '1A'},{id: 101, quantity: 2, grp: '2A'}]
let arr2 = [{id: 101, color: "#FFF"}, {id: 100, color: "#000"}] 

// make lookup
let lookup = arr1.reduce((lookup, item) => lookup.set(item.id, item), new Map)

// assign color to correct object
arr2.forEach(({id, ...rest}) => Object.assign(lookup.get(id), rest))
console.log(arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this

```
    let arr1 = [{
      id: 100,
      quantity: 2,
      grp: 1 A
    }];

    let arr2 = [{
      id: 100,
      color: "#000"
    }];

    arr2.forEach(obj => {

      arr1.find(arr1_element => arr1_element.id == obj.id).color = obj.color;
    });

    console.log(arr1, arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr1 = [{id: 100, quantity: 2, grp: 1A},{...},{...}, ...],

let arr2 = [{id: 100, color: "#000"},{...},{...}, ...],
```

First creating lookup map from `arr2` and then using `.map()` on the `arr1` to assign values from the lookup table.

```
let lookupMap = new Map();
arr2.forEach((val,key)=>{
  lookupMap.set(val.id, val.color);
});

let mappedArray = arr1.map((obj)=> {
  let color = lookupMap.get(obj.id);
  return {...obj, color }
});

// mapped Array would be as 
//[ { id: 100, quantity: 2, grp: '1A', color: '#000' },
// {...},{...} ]
```