# Combining two objects from two different arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays, `orders` and `cartitems`

I want to create a singel payload with information of both of arrays combined. to post to my API using Axios.

I've tried mapping one array (since I only need one item from the other array) and then trying to add the objects together like this:

```
const payload = []
let newArray = []

this.props.cartItems.map((item) => {
  let payloadobject = {
    productName: item.productname,
    amount: item.qty,
    price: item.price,
    order_id: this.props.cart.id,
  }

  newArray = appendObjTo(payload, payloadobject);
})
```

Hoping `newArray` would hold the combined combined array. But get met with the error:

> can't find variable: `appendObjTo`

How do I combine both objects? That are each in side of their own array

edit

current data structure

**catritems**

```
cartItems Array [
  Object {
    "id": 2,
    "price": "6.50",
    "productname": "Baco",
    "qty": 2,

  }
]
```

**orders**

```
orders Array [
  Object {
    "id": 2,
  }
]
```

desired output

newArray Array [
  Object {
    "id": 2,
    "price": "6.50",
    "productname": "Baco",
    "qty": 2,
    "order_id": 1 (hold id from order object),
  }
]

Comment: Please provide _before_ and _after_ view of your data structures.

Comment: `appendObjTo` is simply not defined.

Comment: Do newArray.push(payloadobject) in the last line.

Comment: can you show your implementation of appendObjTo function ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript merging objects by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480008/javascript-merging-objects-by-id)

Comment: @RandyCasburn I've added the structures

Comment: @M1K1O Yes after reviewing it myself I see I missed something

Comment: @frodo2975 I'll check out that question

Comment: @Vishnu Wil do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error message since `appendObjTo` isn't defined. It's not a standard function, and if you've defined it yourself it's probably in another scope.

Instead of `appendObjTo` you could use the `Object.assign` function ([MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)). It could be used like this:

```
newArray = Object.assign({}, payload, payloadobject);
```

However, there's another fault in your code. Right now your assigning each combined object to `newArray`, and at the en it will hold the last combined object, not an array.
The lambda function you supply to `map` should return a new object that you want to replace the input object in the new array. When all objects are looped through the `map` function returns a new array ([MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)). In your case it could be used like this:

```
const payload = [];

let newArray = this.props.cartItems.map((item) => {
    let payloadobject = {
        productName: item.productname,
        amount: item.qty,
        price: item.price,
        order_id: this.props.cart.id
    };

    return Object.assign({ }, payload, payloadobject);
});
```

This will make `newArray` be an array of object where each object is a combination of the whole `payload`, and `payloadobject`.

Hope this helps