# JavaScript: add new property to array elements according to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays.

When comparing, if `arr1` property `id` matches with `arr2` property `id`, then add new property `tag: assign` else add `tag: ''`

I have tried the below code:

```
var result = arr1.filter(({ id: id }) => 
  !arr2.some(({ name: name }) => name === id)
);
```

Sample inputs:

```
var arr1 = [
  {id:1, name: "ram"},
  {id:24, name: "zen"},
  {id: 3, name: "sam"}
]
var arr2 = [
  {id:24, name: "zen"},
  {id: 3, name: "sam"}
]
```

Expected Output:

```
 [
  {id:1, name: "ram", tag:''},
  {id:24, name: "zen", tag: 'yes'},
  {id: 3, name: "sam", tag: 'yes'}
]
```

Comment: also: [JavaScript merging objects by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480008/javascript-merging-objects-by-id)

Comment: The duplicate assigned is for merging arrays, not what OP is looking for.

Answer (score -1):

- Create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of ids in `arr2` using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- Again, using `Array#map`, iterate over `arr1` and set `tag` using [`Set#has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has)

```js
const 
  arr1 = [ {id:1, name: "ram"}, {id:24, name: "zen"}, {id: 3, name: "sam"} ],
  arr2 = [ {id:24, name: "zen"}, {id: 3, name: "sam"} ];
  
const arr2IdsSet = new Set( arr2.map(({ id }) => id) );

const res = arr1.map(e => ({ ...e, tag: arr2IdsSet.has(e.id) ? 'yes' : '' }));

console.log(res);
```